# How to find a BTC/BCC mining node with modified software?

Tags: mining-pools

I want to confirm my non-standard transaction(s) in BTC/BCC network. To do it I have to find mining node with modified software. Is there pool admin who can switch off **SCRIPT_VERIFY_CLEANSTACK** flag on his node?

A special message to mods: this question is strong bitcoin-related. This is not looking for particular software :))

[image]

**Update:** one example is here: https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/6f877c/ This trick will permit to spend funds from https://blockchain.info/address/3DkVqK1rUPZuj8EnPAbKmJ3A8xuZeTseeW in BTC-chain or http://blockdozer.com/insight/address/3DkVqK1rUPZuj8EnPAbKmJ3A8xuZeTseeW in BCC/BCH-chain

If you are interested in it I can publish the spending transaction.

Comment: Hehehe. I am curious about your experiment. Carry on! ;)

Comment: Interesting question, let's see if someone have a good answer for that.

Comment: unfortunately, `+500` is maximum bounty on SE.  I wish I pay more :)

Comment: I'm curious. What does this do exactly?

Comment: maybe you can share here your "non standard" transaction?

Comment: I am not sure that `comments section` is proper place for dumping raw transactions :) I can answer such questions via email. My email is alistermaclin@mail.ru

Comment: MINERS DO NOT DO THIS!  It would allow a block to be mined which illegitimately spends segwit funds.  This person is trying to subvert segwit.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the BCC has been [claimed](https://blockdozer.com/insight/tx/0798a57bc1a130c5f02de4d359334a0e63a3f6cd1ddf11f39d6e7aab5dd29662). As for the BTC, you are not asking a question about the protocol or the software, you are looking for a person controlling mining equipment, and that question is better suited to https://bitcointalk.org than to this site.

Comment: Isn't this site for sharing knowledge? :))) Sometimes the question is more meanful than answers :)))